# getServerSideProps not working using nextJs page routing

Tags: next.js

```
import React from 'react';

function MovieDetails({ Myquery }) {
    console.log(Myquery)
    return <h1>Movie Details</h1>

}
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
    const Myquery = query;
    return {
        props: Myquery,
    }
}
export default MovieDetails;
```

i am using page routing next version is

```
    "next": "13.4.19",
```

console.log showing undefined

suggestions

how to solve thuis

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(query)` in the `getServersideProps` function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `query` can be stringified to JSON, you need to return it like this:

```
return {
  props: { Myquery }
}
```

That way `props` is passed to the page as an object with the key `Myquery`. Note that you cannot pass functions this way, since props are passed as JSON as described in [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props).